# SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

Всем привет!
Поставил сервер java + spring на VPS Ubuntu, запустил, полёт нормальный, но когда пытаюсь выдать JSON с сервера по ссылке http://139.59.164.239:8080/menuserver/dishes выходит ошибка:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Код:
Dish.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dishes")

public class Dish {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
@GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
private long id;

@Column(name = "title_ru", nullable = false, length = 50)
private String titleRu;

@Column(name = "title_eng", nullable = false, length = 50)
private String titleEng;

@Column(name = "description_ru", nullable = false, length = 500)
private String descriptionRu;

@Column(name = "description_eng", nullable = false, length = 500)
private String descriptionEng;

@Column(name = "url", nullable = false, length = 150)
private String url;

@Column(name = "img_url", nullable = false, length = 150)
private String imageUrl;

@Column(name = "weight", nullable = false, length = 5)
private int weight;

@Column(name = "category_id", nullable = false, length = 5)
private int categoryId;

@Column(name = "status", nullable = false, length = 2)
private int status;
далее для всех переменных getter and setter
```

ReminderController.java:

```
@RestController
public class ReminderController {

    @Autowired
    private BasicService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/dishes", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public List<Dish> getAllDishes() {
        return service.getAllDishes();
    }
}
```

База данных на Postgresql, создал базу, создал таблицу таким образом:

```
create table dishes(
id serial,
title_ru text,
title_eng text,
description_ru text,
description_eng text,
url text,
img_url text,
weight integer,
category_id integer,
status integer);
```

Полное описание ошибки можете прочитать по ссылке - http://139.59.164.239:8080/menuserver/dishes
Если боитесь переходить по ссылке, могу выложить полное описание ошибки в этот или следующий пост.
В чем проблема? Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: ****База данных на Postgresql, создал базу, создал таблицу таким образом:***

А где ты вводил это?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самая важная строка в стректрейсе:

> ```
> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: permission denied for relation dishes
> ```

У пользователя, под которым вы выполняете запрос, недостаточно привилегий для доступа к таблице `dishes`.

Comment: Заработало под postgres пользователем, спасибо! ВЫРУЧИЛ!